# How do I insert a lambda expression as a parameter to a mongodb 'collection.find' method?

Tags: c#, mongodb, lambda

I am new to lambda expressions and delegates. I don't exactly know how to use them.
So I have this method that I want to pass a lambda expression parameter to as such (x : x.name == "testName") so I can fetch Mongodb records that has "testname" as a name.

```
public List<BaseModel> get(*lambda expression here*)
    {


        List<User> users = Database.userCollectionObjs.Find(*lambda expression here*).ToList();
        List<BaseModel> baseModels = new List<BaseModel>();
        foreach (User user in users)
        {

            baseModels.Add(user);
        }

        return baseModels;

    }
```

obviously if I do it like this:

```
        List<User> users = Database.userCollectionObjs.Find(user => user.name == "testuser").ToList();
```

it works. 
but how do I pass this expression as a parameter to my get() and then insert it in the userCollectionObjs.Find

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That [**`Find`**](https://api.mongodb.com/csharp/current/html/M_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoCollectionExtensions_Find__1_1.htm) extension method is defined as

```
public static IFindFluent<TDocument, TDocument> Find<TDocument>(
    this IMongoCollection<TDocument> collection,
    Expression<Func<TDocument, bool>> filter, //<-- NOTE THE FILTER
    FindOptions options = null
)
```

Take note of the `filter` parameter's type.

You would need to pass the appropriate filter for your collection.

Assuming `userCollectionObjs` holds `User` then the `get()` would look something like

```
public List<BaseModel> get(Expression<Func<User, bool>> filter) {
    List<User> users = Database.userCollectionObjs.Find(filter).ToList();
    List<BaseModel> baseModels = new List<BaseModel>();
    foreach (User user in users) {
        baseModels.Add(user);
    }
    return baseModels;
}
```

This would then allow for the invocation of `get` function as desired

```
List<BaseModel> baseModels = myClass.get(user => user.name == "testuser");
```